# Check a set of items within a table and cross with another structure | SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my store I can sell items together (packages with a predefined list of products). However, on the website, the system only shows me the product codes separately, it doesn't tell me when the sale was TOGETHER (in a package format).

I have a reference table where it shows me the product codes and the quantity that make up a certain package (which I call set_products):

```
WITH ReferenceTable AS (
  SELECT 'set123' AS set_products, 'itemA' AS product_id, 2 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set123' AS set_products, 'itemB' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set456' AS set_products, 'itemZ' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set456' AS set_products, 'itemY' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity
)
SELECT * FROM ReferenceTable
```

[image]

In this example I know that package 'set123' is composed of 2 products with code 'itemA' plus 1 product with code 'itemB'. And the package 'set456' is composed of 1 product with code 'ItemZ' plus 1 product with code 'ItemY'.

In my sales table, I have the ID of the ticket (transaction) and the list of products sold within each one.

```
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT 153612 AS ticket_id, 'itemA' AS product_id, 2 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 153612 AS ticket_id, 'itemB' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 153612 AS ticket_id, 'itemZ' AS product_id, 3 AS quantity UNION ALL

  SELECT 542652 AS ticket_id, 'itemA' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 542652 AS ticket_id, 'itemB' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 625167 AS ticket_id, 'itemA' AS product_id, 4 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 625167 AS ticket_id, 'itemB' AS product_id, 2 AS quantity
)
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

[image]

In this example I have 3 different transactions. The first one (153612) sold the product set (2x ItemA + 1x ItemB) but had an additional item sold individually (ItemZ). In this case the expected output would be the package ID on the first two rows, but not on the third.

The second transaction (542652) has the two items that make up the package, but the quantity is not the same, so the expected output is NULL.

And finally the third transaction (625167) which is the sale of exactly 2 complete packages (these cases seem to be a little more complicated to identify).

I'm trying to identify these cases within a huge table, where the expected output is the product set code identification. Something like this:

[image]

I'm using BigQuery but I accept suggestions in any other SQL. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare max/min ratio of the package products in a ticket to get  relevant package / ticket pairs. Not sure what you want if a product in a ticket takes part in more than one  relevant package.

```
WITH ReferenceTable AS (
  SELECT 'set123' AS set_products, 'itemA' AS product_id, 2 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set123' AS set_products, 'itemB' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set456' AS set_products, 'itemZ' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set456' AS set_products, 'itemY' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity ),

),
MyTable AS (
  SELECT 153612 AS ticket_id, 'itemA' AS product_id, 2 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 153612 AS ticket_id, 'itemB' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 153612 AS ticket_id, 'itemZ' AS product_id, 3 AS quantity UNION ALL

  SELECT 542652 AS ticket_id, 'itemA' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 542652 AS ticket_id, 'itemB' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 625167 AS ticket_id, 'itemA' AS product_id, 4 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 625167 AS ticket_id, 'itemB' AS product_id, 2 AS quantity
)
SELECT rt.set_products, mt.ticket_id, max(mt.quantity * 1.0 / rt.quantity) nmbrOfPkgs
from ReferenceTable rt
left join MyTable mt on mt.product_id = rt.product_id
group by mt.ticket_id, rt.set_products
having max(mt.quantity * 1.0 / rt.quantity) = min(mt.quantity * 1.0 / rt.quantity)
   and count(*) = (select count(*) 
              from ReferenceTable rt1  
              where rt1.set_products = rt.set_products)
```

Comment: The same product can be inside different packages, but the STRUCTURE of the packages will be different, so this type of problem should not occur.... The solution you sent me returns only two rows, however the ticket 625167 - which is composed of 2 packages - it only returns one row - I need it to return two because there are two sales of the package...

Comment: Added the nmbr of packages, see the edited answer

Comment: I don't think this is the way to go... The resolution worked for this example (which is great, was the question I initially asked, so thanks a lot!). However, I just apply a new package and the result no longer works.... ############# WITH ReferenceTable AS (
  SELECT 'set123' AS set_products, 'itemA' AS product_id, 2 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set123' AS set_products, 'itemB' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set456' AS set_products, 'itemZ' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'set456' AS set_products, 'itemY' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity
) #############

Comment: .......complementing the previous answer....... The only itemZ inside the ticketID 153612 already marks me as a package sale (which is not right).

Comment: You are right, the query should also take the count of items into account . See the edited version

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this resolution worked for almost every case I have in the database. I already indicated your answer as correct.
However I have an extra case where the rule doesn't apply correctly, I appreciate if you can help me with that too. If not, that's fine too...   Imagine that the package 'set123' is composed of 3x 'ItemA' + 1x 'ItemB' (WITH in the comment below). In this case, the Ticket_ID '625167' should be indicated as a package sale + one individual itemA + one individual itemB. However the query doesn't return this.

Comment: WITH ReferenceTable AS (
  SELECT 'bundle123' AS set_products, 'item A' AS product_id, 3 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bundle123' AS set_products, 'item B' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bundleABC' AS set_products, 'item Y' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bundleABC' AS set_products, 'item Z' AS product_id, 1 AS quantity
)